# how to remove element in vue directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to create a v-if like directive, but i can't find a way to remove element
so i hide the element like this..

```
<Button v-check="'aaa'" type="primary">aaa</Button>
<Button v-check="'bbb'" type="primary">bbb</Button>
```

```
Vue.directive('check', {
    bind(el, binding, vnode, old) {
        if (binding.value === 'aaa') {
            el.style.display = 'none'
        }
    }
})
```

i want to remove the element totally

Is there any way that i can remove the element?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ok, i find a way

```
Vue.directive('check', {
  inserted(el, binding, vnode, old) {
    if (binding.value === 'aaa') {
      vnode.elm.parentElement.removeChild(vnode.elm)
    }
  }
})
```